# Tracing system call on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, process, system-calls

The main task I have to carry out, is to trace the system call of processes in ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Problem is, I am unable to trace them continuously, i.e. as soon as they are added to the system, they should get traced.

Is there any kind of signal or interrupt which can inform the user about a newly added process in the system?

Comment: Check if `http://linux.die.net/man/8/autrace` could help you.

Comment: @ott-- I have already gone through audit utility, it does not help. I am working with _strace_. Problem is it does not respond until the process to which it is attached gets terminated.

Comment: What's the cmdline you use to trace what process?

Comment: I extract the pid of running process using *ps* command and then feed them to *strace* as `strace -c -p <pid> -o <out_put>`

Comment: Have you tried adding the `-f` option? Tho it was not helpful for me e.g. with apache.

Comment: @ott-- IIRC Apache uses `vfork` heavily, so you'd need `-F` (which isn't 100% reliable).

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which processes do you want to start? How are they started? Do you want to trace their subprocesses as well? Why don't you want to work with autrace?

Comment: @Gilles I want to trace each and every process initiated by the non root user (assuming there is only one user for simplicity). The purpose behind this is to develop an Intrusion Detection System based on system call trace of legitimate and illegitimate programs.

Comment: @JunaidSiddiqui Then the audit facility would seem to be the way to go. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @Gilles: Hmm you are right, i am going through the documentation right now, hope its fruitful. I would really appreciate if you answer one more query, since i am a newbie with unix, i was wondering whether __audit__ will work with Ubuntu 12.04 or not.